How to cancel nav activation if it cant pass validation
I have a nav menu and each tab has different form. I got top nav menu for example
***
> A FORM B FORM C FORM
> -form- 
>back click next click
***

I have a valitadation for top nav menu and next click every form user cannot past next form if user dont fill form input validation works but when click form b for example i think ngbnavlink makes it active nav title ,validation dont show form menu but user needs to click back form a. i dont want to user click back to form a to go form b so i cant click form b consecutively.

please share stackblitz with the issue happening, steps for replication and expected result from stackblitz
